# Facebook Graph API returns false with a fanpage id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having problems with the facebook graph api, I have an iframe app that return all the albums from and specific fanpage, but from the past 3 days it stops working, I figured out that I was because the API returns me false, here is the URL:

http://graph.facebook.com/347077778656045

and here is the fanpage URL:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Muebles-HRP/347077778656045

my facebook id is 347077778656045, and if I use another fanpage id the app works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `false` being returned means that the authenticated user's `access_token` doesn't have permission to view that object. Similar post: [Graph API for user returns false even with a valid user access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357493/graph-api-for-user-returns-false-even-with-a-valid-user-access-token)

Comment: I found the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843796/graph-api-returns-false-on-fan-page-details

Other administrator changed the setting and set country restrictions, so as you said, i need a valid access_token, or to disable that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to access that page.

Have you unpublished page? If so only admins can see that page

FYI : [FAQ](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=184605634921611)